# DataTables Export Button Issue - Button Not Displaying

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to display an export button in the center of the screen and below my DataTable. The button isn't displaying at all. I've downloaded the DataTable files and they are hosted on my server (hence the local references).

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables/datatables.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/datatables.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#example').DataTable( {
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
      {
        extend: 'collection',
        text: 'Export',
        buttons: [
          'copy',
          'excel',
          'csv',
          'pdf',
          'print'
        ]
      }         
    ]
  });
} );
</script>
```

I am wondering if I'm just missing a dependency although I used the DataTables download builder.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure you've imported everything you need and take a look at:
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/simple.html

External code:

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.flash.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.print.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js
https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js
https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js
```

Working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.0/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>


<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks. I decided to use: dom: 'frtipB' to display the buttons at the bottom of the table. Just wondering, is there anyway to keep the "Show # Entries" when you use these buttons?

Comment: That solves it. The dom options are a little confusing at first but I think I've got it now.

Comment: Thanks In my case, missing of {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    }  inside DataTable() was the issue :-)

Comment: Its missing the l flag in dom. l for "length changing input control".

 dom: 'lBfrtip' otherwise Show Entries dropdown won't appear.

Answer (score 1):

All the above answers are almost correct but still, the buttons are not showing.
You can also use the following trick to display export buttons.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            ]
        });
        $('#btn-place').html(table.buttons().container());
```

Now create a div where you want to add these buttons.

```
<div id="btn-place"></div>
```

[Reference link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/javascript/export-buttons-wont-display-on-datatable)