# Datatable export Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

Datatable is working but it's not showing the export buttons

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#table').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: ['copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5'
    ]
} );} );
```

These are the imports

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/b-1.5.1/b-colvis-1.5.1/b-flash-1.5.1/b-html5-1.5.1/r-2.2.1/datatables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/b-1.5.1/b-colvis-1.5.1/b-flash-1.5.1/b-html5-1.5.1/r-2.2.1/datatables.min.js"></script>   
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="  https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Those "imports" are a bit of a mess... I see some duplicates in there. That might be part of the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dataTables Export to Excel button is not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966718/datatables-export-to-excel-button-is-not-showing)