# DataTables Jquery File Export did not show the button

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, vue.js

I had use the dataTables jquery without plugin one. The table is work fine with showing data. But if I implemented the file export, the button did not showing or appearing on the table.

Package.vue

```
         this.dataTable = $("#package-rank-table").DataTable({
            dom: "lfBrtip",
            buttons: [
              {
                extend: "print",
                text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i>',
                titleAttr: "Print",
                title: "Redemption Invoice List",
                exportOptions: {
                  columns: [0, 1, 2],
                },
              },
              {
                extend: "copyHtml5",
                text: '<i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>',
                titleAttr: "Copy",
                title: " > STOCK List",
                exportOptions: {
                  columns: [0, 1, 2],
                },
              },
              {
                extend: "excelHtml5",
                text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
                titleAttr: "Excel",
                title: " > STOCK List",
                exportOptions: {
                  columns: [0, 1, 2],
                },
              },
              {
                extend: "csvHtml5",
                text: '<i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>',
                titleAttr: "CSV",
                title: " > STOCK List",
                exportOptions: {
                  columns: [0, 1, 2],
                },
              },
              {
                extend: "pdfHtml5",
                text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>',
                titleAttr: "PDF",
                download: "open",
                title: " > STOCK List",
                exportOptions: {
                  columns: [0, 1, 2],
                },
              },
            ],
          });
```

This is the html on vue component

```
            <table
              class="table table-bordered"
              id="package-rank-table"
              width="100%"
              cellspacing="0"
            >
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>No</th>
                  <th>Package Name</th>
                  <th>Total Package Purchased</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <th>No</th>
                  <th>Package Name</th>
                  <th>Total Package Purchased</th>
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
              <tbody>
              </tbody>
              </table>
```

And also this head is to get the link from datatable

```
    <!--Datatable -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
```

I hope can help me solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: show your console errors some jquery conflictiong so buttons are not displayying

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dataTables Export to Excel button is not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966718/datatables-export-to-excel-button-is-not-showing)

Answer (score 0):

add these javascript files in footer and styles links in header then your problem will be solved .

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nvm, I solved. Basically I put wrong place for those script. Need to put in body. Thanks alot.