# how to add datatables button in my specific function on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

so this is my global function for every file

```
App.Cars = {
    dataTableLoad: function (url, columns) {
        $(".data-table").DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            responsive: true,
            ajax: {
                url: url,
                method: "POST",
            },
            columns: columns,
            
           
        });
    },
}
```

this is how i am loading it in my page

```
App.Cars.dataTableLoad("{{ route('cars.submodels.listing') }}", [{
            data: 'uid',
            name: 'uid'
        },
        {
            data: 'make_id',
            name: 'make_id'
        },
        {
            data: 'model_id',
            name: 'model_id'
        },
        {
            data: 'name',
            name: 'name'
        },
        {
            data: 'name_ar',
            name: 'name_ar'
        },
        {
            data: 'year_from',
            name: 'year_from'
        },
        {
            data: 'year_to',
            name: 'year_to'
        },
        {
            data: 'car_source',
            name: 'car_source'
        },
        {
            data: 'sub_model_image',
            name: 'sub_model_image'
        },
        {
            data: 'action',
            name: 'action',
            orderable: false,
            searchable: false
        },

    ])
```

so i want to add print csv and excel button in my only this page how to do this ? also i have added the buttons like this

```
       App.Cars.dataTableLoad("{{ route('cars.submodels.listing') }}", [{
            data: 'uid',
            name: 'uid'
        },
        {
            data: 'make_id',
            name: 'make_id'
        },
        {
            data: 'model_id',
            name: 'model_id'
        },
        {
            data: 'name',
            name: 'name'
        },
        {
            data: 'name_ar',
            name: 'name_ar'
        },
        {
            data: 'year_from',
            name: 'year_from'
        },
        {
            data: 'year_to',
            name: 'year_to'
        },
        {
            data: 'car_source',
            name: 'car_source'
        },
        {
            data: 'sub_model_image',
            name: 'sub_model_image'
        },
        {
            data: 'action',
            name: 'action',
            orderable: false,
            searchable: false
        },

    ], {
        dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-lg-4'l><'col-sm-12 col-lg-4 text-center'B><'col-sm-12 col-lg-4'f>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-12'rt>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-12'i>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-12'p>>",
        buttons: {
            dom: {
                container: {
                    className: "dt-buttons",
                },
                button: {
                    className: "btn btn-secondary",
                },
            },
            buttons: ["copy", "excel", "csv"],
        },
    });
```

but it is not showing any button on browser and there is not even any error what should i do now?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966718/datatables-export-to-excel-button-is-not-showing

Comment: @Adi Basically all the buttons were working fine when they  were in my global function but the problem is global function is used in almost every file i just want buttons in only one file so i just want to show them in only that page where datatables are loading i have tried like i have shown here but not working is there any way?